# Android DataBinding No field device of type I in class L***/****/common/BR

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have a project were I'm trying to share common code between different apps that will be contained.

Right now I only have a common module as an android library where I moved a single fragment and all his linked resources so I can used it on my main application module.

I'm able to display the layout correctly, but when I'm trying to bind a variable to this layout I'm getting the following error:
`java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field device of type I in class L***/****/common/BR; or its superclasses (declaration of '**.****.common.BR' appears in /data/app/***.****.******-9VGDieZHqLKJUD0xhdmawA==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk)`

Looking at the stack trace the issue happens on my fragment generated data binding class in this method:

```
public void setDevice(@Nullable **.***.common.vo.Device Device) {
    this.mDevice = Device;
    synchronized(this) {
        mDirtyFlags |= 0x1L;
    }
    notifyPropertyChanged(BR.device);
    super.requestRebind();
}
```

Specifically in this call: `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.device)`.

So apparently the generated class cannot find the `BR.device` in the merged BR file, but it also stays that it was found in a split APK...

I don't know if this is a configuration issue or a bug in the merge process...

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if the package names for both modules are the same.
I had similar error and it was due to my lib module having the 
same package name as my app module.

Example:

com.app.example    (app module package name)
com.app.example    (lib module package name)

I changed to this:

com.app.example    (app module package name)
com.lib.example    (lib module package name)

Comment: Indeed it was a package name... It took me more time that I expected since the refactoring was failing (it was changing all my projects package name).